# Como escapar de um processo recursivo de salvar log de erro de uma base de dados - PHP?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, recursão, log

Eu tenho uma classe que salva o log numa base de dados baseado em quanquer erro de transação nessa base.

O fato é que o processo de salvar esse log tbm é uma transação e em um cenário hipotético um processo qualquer poderia gerar um erro, e em seguida esse processo desencadeiaria o processo de salvar o erro e esse novo processo tbm geraria um erro chamando a si mesmo. Esse processo não teria fim.

Aqui o código do **catch**:

```
 catch (PDOException $e) {     
                self::$exceptionObjc = $e;  
                self::saveLogMsgInDb(["exceptionObjc"=>self::$exceptionObjc,"sql"=>self::$sql]);
                self::$arrCatchConnResult = self::saveLogMsg(["exceptionObjc"=>self::$exceptionObjc,"sql"=>self::$sql]);
                self::$conn = null;
                if (self::$die) {
                    $msg = self::$arrCatchConnResult["displayMsgHTML"];
                    die($msg);
                }
            }
```

Aqui o código do **saveLogInDB**:

```
public static function saveLogMsgInDb($saveLogsParam = NULL) {              

       $excepObjc = $saveLogsParam['exceptionObjc'] ;

       $sql = $saveLogsParam['sql'];
       $logMsg = $excepObjc->getMessage();   
       $StackTrace = json_encode($excepObjc->getTrace());  
       $exceptionObjc = json_encode($excepObjc);  
       //$StackTrace = addslashes(json_encode($excepObjc->getTrace()));  
       //$exceptionObjc = addslashes(json_encode($excepObjc)); 

        $arrSql=[
            "db_Logs"=>[
                     "msg"=>[$logMsg,PDO::PARAM_STR], 
                     "sql"=>[$sql,PDO::PARAM_STR],           
                     "StackTrace"=>[$StackTrace,PDO::PARAM_STR],
                     "exceptionObjc"=>[$exceptionObjc,PDO::PARAM_STR]
            ]
        ];



        self::set_values($arrSql); 
        //die();

    }
```

Uma possível solução seria usar um `die()` dentro de saveLogMsgInDb() mas isso iria fazer o site parar.

A minha pergunta é como seria uma abordagem que fizesse escapar desse processo recursivo sem quebrar o processo do site web?

Comment: Precisaria de mais informação para responder melhor. Mas com os dados que tenho, se os erros forem gravados numa tabela própria, ou com um campo único, procuraria por esse valor dentro do catch e se tivesse é porque era uma tentativa de gravar um erro (que também deu erro) e não tentava grava outra vez.

Comment: E como escapar sem quebrar o processo, ou seja, sem o die()?